# Tex macro needed to display mercurial keywords

Tags: macros, revision-control, mercurial

I have mercurial keywords in a latex doc which I wish to process.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% This macro is an example based on the Tex FAQ:  
% https://texfaq.org/FAQ-RCS
% We define \hgDate and \hgRevision macros.
\def\hg$#1: #2 ${\expandafter\def\csname hg#1\endcsname{#1: #2 }}

% This is what will be in the preamble if keyword expansion is turned on.
\hg$Revision: 123 $     % this is auto expanded by hg - do not change 
\hg$Date: 2015-01-08 $  % this is auto expanded by hg - do not change

% But ... if keyword expansion is turned off or not set the above will 
% be like the two lines below. Note: commented out as this does not work yet.
% \hg$Revision$    
% \hg$Date$ 
\begin{document}

Minimal example of plain tex macro to process mercurial keyword expansions.
If \verb+\hg$Date$+ exists in the preamble then we wish the macro 
\verb+\hgDate+ to display ``Date: None''. If \verb+\hg$Date: 2014-11-10 $+
exists in the preamble then we wish the macro \verb+\hgDate+ to display 
``Date: 2014-11-10''. Similarly for \verb+\hg$Revision$+. 

This doc is \hgRevision and \hgDate 
\end{document}
```

The above works for $Date xx $ and $Revision 12 $ but not $Date$ or $Revision$ as it hasn't got a 2nd parameter.

There are svn latex packages but they use a different format for the keywords than mercurial so don't work for just a date. I wish to use a simple TeX macro as my latex docs get used by Windows and Mac users I just want to add a short tex macro at the top rather than users having to install new latex packages. Below are some of my attempts that are plainly wrong.

This attempt tests for the 2nd parameter being nothing:

```
\def\foo{}%
\def\hg$#1: #2 $%
{\expandafter\def\csname hg#1\endcsname%
{\if\foo#2\foo #1: None\else #1: #2\fi}%
}
%\hg$Revision$  
\hg$Revision: 123 $   
\hg$Date: 2015-01-08 $ 
\hgDate \hspace{2ex} \hgRevision
```

This attempt tests if the 2nd parameter is empty:

```
\def\hg$#1: #2 ${\expandafter\def\csname hg#1\endcsname%
{#1: \def\temp{#2\unskip}%
\ifx\temp\empty
  None
\else 
  #2
\fi}%
}
%\hg$Revision$  
\hg$Revision: 123 $   
\hg$Date: 2015-01-08 $ 
\hgDate \hspace{2ex} \hgRevision
```

This attempt tries to use detokenize to see if param 2 is empty:

```
\def\hg$#1: #2 $%
{\expandafter\def\csname hg#1\endcsname%
{#1: \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax yy\else xx\fi}%
}
%\hg$Revision$  
\hg$Revision: 123 $  
\hg$Date: 2015-01-08 $ 
\hgDate \hspace{2ex} \hgRevision
```

Each fails when there is no 2nd parameter.
Perhaps I should be trying to strip the $ or change it's catcode? More probably I need to understand TeX better!

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please clarify what your question is, maybe even adding an example of what you want the result to be?

Answer (score 3):

I find it convenient using `xparse` and `expl3` features, which avoid complicated cases.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hg}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}r$$}
 {%
  \processhg#1%
 }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\processhg}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
  {\hg_define_hg:nn { #1 } { None } }
  {\hg_define_hg:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hg_define_hg:nn
 {
  \cs_gset:cpx {hg#1}{ \tl_trim_spaces:n { #2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% This is what will be in the preamble if keyword expansion is turned on.
\hg$Revision: 123 $     % this is auto expanded by hg - do not change 
\hg$Date: 2015-01-08 $  % this is auto expanded by hg - do not change

\begin{document}

Revision: \hgRevision; Date: \hgDate.

Now we emulate calling the macros without parameters

\hg$Revision$    
\hg$Date$ 

Revision: \hgRevision; Date: \hgDate.

\end{document}
```

The macro `\hg` has one argument delimited by `$` signs. The argument is split at the colon into two parts, but if no colon is found, the second argument will receive a special value that makes the test `\IfNoValueTF` true.

The split argument is still denoted by `#1` and is passed to a second macro for processing. This, in turn, will call an internal function with the appropriate arguments (`None` in case there was no colon).

[image]

Comment: That works :-) and if I make a small change I don't have to add the Date: and Revision: before the commands.  
`{\hg_define_hg:nn { #1 } { #1:\ None }}`
`{\hg_define_hg:nn { #1 } { #1:\ #2 }}`  I had the xparse package already, not sure if my other colleagues have that on Windows/Mac.

Comment: This morning on the train I read the xparse docs so now going through to understand it. I didn't realise I could use LaTeX3 stuff in LaTeX2e. The ExplSyntax is new to to me (I'm using Tex Live 2014) and makes the code more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I were to do without any package, this would be something in the following style. It *assumes* something like `$name$` or `$name:<space>stuff<space>$`. If spaces were optional, the code would have to be correspondingly adapted, which is not hard (for someone versed in `TeX`'s macro language!).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\hg #1{\def\hg $##1${\hg@ ##1:#1#1:\hg@}}
\hg { }
\def\hg@ #1: #2 :#3\hg@{\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \@namedef{hg#1}{#1: None}%
    \else
    \@namedef{hg#1}{#1: #2}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% This is what will be in the preamble if keyword expansion is turned on.
\hg$Revision: 123 $     % this is auto expanded by hg - do not change 
\hg$Date: 2015-01-08 $  % this is auto expanded by hg - do not change

% \hg$Revision$    
% \hg$Date$ 
\begin{document}

Minimal example of plain tex macro to process mercurial keyword expansions.
If \verb+\hg$Date$+ exists in the preamble then we wish the macro 
\verb+\hgDate+ to display ``Date: None''. If \verb+\hg$Date: 2014-11-10 $+
exists in the preamble then we wish the macro \verb+\hgDate+ to display 
``Date: 2014-11-10''. Similarly for \verb+\hg$Revision$+. 

This doc is \hgRevision{} and \hgDate.


\hg$Revision$    
\hg$Date$ 
This doc is \hgRevision{} and \hgDate.
\end{document}
```

> [image: mercurial tags]

Comment: Thanks jfbu. This is really nice and short and also works well. I tried it by adding it to a hg.tex and \input it into my docs. Works nicely. Will have to read my Knuth TeX book to follow how it works. Will take me some days to understand and document it for myself. Thanks from Mike.

Comment: @MikeL the TeX guru thing here is with `\hg` which first redefines itself in order to be a delimited macro whose parameter text contains two successive space tokens. This also requires doubling the `#` character. This is pure `TeX`, not `LaTeX` which has no user interface for that. Then `\hg@` is simpler, it finds in `#2` either an empty thing, meaning we were of the `$name$` sort (with no colon), or `#2` is non empty and we were of the `$name: stuff $` sort. As it stands the thing will break if either the space before or after stuff is non-existent

Answer (score 1):

In case the input-pattern either is
`\hg$⟨name⟩$`
or is
`\hg$⟨name⟩:⟨space⟩⟨stuff⟩⟨space⟩$`
, whereby

- *⟨name⟩* does not contain a colon trailed by a space (the sequence `:` )  and
- *⟨stuff⟩* does not contain a space trailed by a colon (the sequence  `:`)

, you can try with delimited arguments.

But be aware that one level of curly braces surrounding everything between `$...$` and one level of curly braces surrounding everything else of *⟨name⟩* and one level of curly braces surrounding everything else of *⟨stuff⟩* will be stripped off if present.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\hg $#1${\hg@ #1: {None/Default} :\hg@}
\def\hg@ #1: #2 :#3\hg@{\@namedef{hg#1}{#1: #2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Calls to \verb|\hgRevision|/\verb|\hgDate| are nested between parentheses so you can see if spaces slipped in.

\bigskip

\par \textbf{Revision/Date empty:}

\hg$Revision$    
\hg$Date$ 

\par (\hgRevision)
\par (\hgDate)

\par \textbf{Without whatsoever surrounding curly braces:}

\hg$Revision: 123 $
\hg$Date: 2015-01-08 $

\par (\hgRevision)
\par (\hgDate)

\par \textbf{With surrounding curly braces that get stripped off:}

\hg${{Revision}: {123} }$
\hg${{Date}: {2015-01-08} }$

\par (\hgRevision)
\par (\hgDate)

\end{document}
```

[image]

If for some reason you wish to prevent the stripping of braces, you can split the mechanism so that each delimited argument is processed by another macro after something was prepended:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\hg${\hg@.}
\def\hg@#1${\hg@@#1: {None/Default} :\hg@@}
%\def\hg@#1${\hg@@#1: None/Default :\hg@@}
\def\hg@@#1: {\expandafter\hg@@i\expandafter{\hg@@gobbledot#1}.}
\def\hg@@i#1#2 :{\expandafter\hg@@ii\expandafter{\hg@@gobbledot#2}{#1}}
\def\hg@@ii#1#2#3\hg@@{\@namedef{hg#2}{#2: #1}}
\def\hg@@gobbledot.{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Calls to \verb|\hgRevision|/\verb|\hgDate| are nested between parentheses so you can see if spaces slipped in.

\bigskip

\par \textbf{Revision/Date empty:}

\hg$Revision$    
\hg$Date$ 

\par (\hgRevision)
\par (\hgDate)
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\string\hgRevision=\meaning\hgRevision}
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\string\hgDate=\meaning\hgDate}

\par \textbf{Without whatsoever surrounding curly braces:}

\hg$Revision: 123 $
\hg$Date: 2015-01-08 $

\par (\hgRevision)
\par (\hgDate)
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\string\hgRevision=\meaning\hgRevision}
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\string\hgDate=\meaning\hgDate}

\par \textbf{With surrounding curly braces that do not get stripped off:}

\hg$Revision: {123} $
\hg$Date: {2015-01-08} $

\par (\hgRevision)
\par (\hgDate)
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\string\hgRevision=\meaning\hgRevision}
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\string\hgDate=\meaning\hgDate}

\hg${Revision}: {123} $
\hg${Date}: {2015-01-08} $

\par (\csname hg{Revision}\endcsname)
\par (\csname hg{Date}\endcsname)
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\expandafter\string\csname hg{Revision}\endcsname=\expandafter\meaning\csname hg{Revision}\endcsname}
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\expandafter\string\csname hg{Date}\endcsname=\expandafter\meaning\csname hg{Date}\endcsname}

\hg${{Revision}: {123} }$
\hg${{Date}: {2015-01-08} }$

\par (\csname hg{{Revision}: {123} }\endcsname)
\par (\csname hg{{Date}: {2015-01-08} }\endcsname)
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\expandafter\string\csname hg{{Revision}: {123} }\endcsname=\expandafter\meaning\csname hg{{Revision}: {123} }\endcsname}
\par {\tt\frenchspacing\expandafter\string\csname hg{{Date}: {2015-01-08} }\endcsname=\expandafter\meaning\csname hg{{Date}: {2015-01-08} }\endcsname}

\end{document}
```

[image]